# what is the right form for program crystal report in asp.net? and visual basic

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, reportviewer, report

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim rptv As New rptVenta()
    Session("vseleccionada") = GridView1.SelectedRow().Cells(1).Text.ToString()
    Dim daove As New DAOVenta()
    Dim tabla As New DataTable()
    tabla = daove.ImprimirFactura(Session("vseleccionada").ToString(), Session("nombreusuario").ToString())
    'Label2.Text = tabla.Rows(0)(3).ToString()
    '  rptv.SetDatabaseLogon("ventas.triton", "triton")
    '   rptv.SetDatabaseLogon("ventas.triton", "triton", "alumno-auc", "admodos")

    rptv.SetDataSource(tabla)
    rptv.SetDatabaseLogon("ventas.triton", "triton", ".", "admodos")

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptv
    rptv.Load("..\GUI\rptVenta.rpt")
    CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo().Item(0).ConnectionInfo().DatabaseName = "admodos"
    CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo().Item(0).ConnectionInfo().IntegratedSecurity = True
    CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo().Item(0).ConnectionInfo().Password = "triton"
    CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo().Item(0).ConnectionInfo().ServerName = "."
    CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo().Item(0).ConnectionInfo().UserID = "ventas.triton"
    ' CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("USER", "PASSWORD", "SERVIDOR", "Base de datos")
    CrystalReportViewer1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White

    'CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind()

    Label2.Text = Session("vseleccionada").ToString() + Session("nombreusuario").ToString()

End Sub
```

i got a bug as this

```
The report requested additional information needed.
```

then, what are the right step to get it work? i am programming in visual basic, visual studio 2008, sql server 2008 r2.

Comment: What exactly your exception is?

Comment: @VMAtm how can i watch the report, i dont want to get the message "the report requested additional information needed"

Comment: "The report requested additional information needed" sounds like an exception message that you wrote yourself (or someone in your team). There's not a single hit on Google. Can you search your solution for that phrase and find out how it is called?

Comment: See my answer below, but I believe this is a valid error from Crystal. I seem to remember that it was the way the database connection was setup, hence the SetDBLogonForReport function which loops through all the tables and set the connection information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recieved this error before. I cannot remember exactly how I fixed (it happened 2-3 years ago) it but here is the code from the project. I had to convert it into VB but I compiled it and ran it and it worked fine.  By the way this was in an ASP.Net web form page so this is from the code behind. The code from the page simply has the CrystalReportViewer.

**References:**

- CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
- CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework
- CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore
- CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
- CrystalDecisions.Shared
- CrystalDecisions.Web

```
    Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
    Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

        ConfigureCrystalReports()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ConfigureCrystalReports()
        Dim myConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
        myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "ReportDatabase"
        myConnectionInfo.UserID = "ReportUser"
        myConnectionInfo.Password = "ReportPassword"
        myConnectionInfo.ServerName = "ReportServer"
        Dim ParamArrayList As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

        aReport = New ReportDocument()
        Dim reportPath As String = Server.MapPath("Report\ReportName.rpt")
        aReport.Load(reportPath)

        Dim Param as ArrayList 
        Param.Add("Value")

        SetCurrentValuesForParameterField(aReport, Param, "@Param1")
        myCrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = aReport 
        SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo, aReport)

    End Sub

    Private Sub SetDBLogonForReport(ByVal myConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo, ByVal myReportDocument As ReportDocument)
        Dim myTables As Tables = myReportDocument.Database.Tables
        For Each myTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In myTables
           Dim myTableLogonInfo As TableLogOnInfo = myTable.LogOnInfo
           myTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = myConnectionInfo
           myTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(myTableLogonInfo)
        Next
    End Sub

        Private Sub SetCurrentValuesForParameterField(ByVal myReportDocument As ReportDocument, ByVal myArrayList As ArrayList, ByVal ParameterFieldName As String)
            Dim currentParameterValues As ParameterValues = New ParameterValues()

            For Each submittedValue As Object In myArrayList
                Dim myParameterDiscreteValue As ParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
                myParameterDiscreteValue.Value = submittedValue.ToString()
                currentParameterValues.Add(myParameterDiscreteValue)
            Next

            Dim myParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions = myReportDocument.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
            Dim myParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition = myParameterFieldDefinitions(ParameterFieldName)
            myParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(currentParameterValues)
        End Sub

        Private Sub SetCurrentValuesForParameterField(ByVal myReportDocument As ReportDocument, ByVal myArrayList As ArrayList, ByVal ParameterFieldName As String, ByVal SubReportName As String)
            Dim currentParameterValues As ParameterValues = New ParameterValues()

            For Each submittedValue As Object In myArrayList
                Dim myParameterDiscreteValue As ParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
                myParameterDiscreteValue.Value = submittedValue.ToString()
                currentParameterValues.Add(myParameterDiscreteValue)
            Next

            Dim myParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions = myReportDocument.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
            Dim myParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition = myParameterFieldDefinitions(ParameterFieldName, SubReportName)
            myParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(currentParameterValues)
        End Sub
```